# xorg.conf for two monitors, single ati graphics card

Tags: ati, graphics, xorg, multiple-monitors

There are many iterations of this question, few with actual working answers, so after a few hours of trying to get it working on my machine, I will post my solution.

How do I configure my Ubuntu laptop to use an external monitor as well as the built-in screen, while allowing me to drag windows across the boundary?

Comment: As you have noticed, it is difficult (or maybe impossible) to get dual/multiple monitors to work well with the ATI graphics driver.  I tried the version that comes with Ubuntu 14.04 and I tried the version from the AMD website (fglrx-14.301.1001), but both failed in the same way (the same content was displayed in multiple places in a very confusing way).  **I found that you can keep the ATI driver installed, but use `amdcccle` to select "Power-saving GPU" (Intel) when you want to use multiple monitors.**  In my case, the Intel is just as fast anyway (for basic 3D w/o anti-aliasing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely to be hardware-dependent, so your mileage may vary.

My hardware is:

```
HP Zbook 14, with dual Intel and ATI Radeon HD 8730M GPUs.
```

The relevant lines of `sudo lspci` are

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8730M]
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and the output of `fglrxinfo` is

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon (TM) HD 8500M/8700M
OpenGL version string: 4.3.12798 Compatibility Profile Context FireGL 13.35.1005
```

After much playing around with xinerama options and so forth, the following `xorg.conf` file works for me

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "amd-layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
    Option     "Xinerama"  "off"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    HorizSync    30.0 - 60.0
    VertRefresh  50.0 - 60.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-1"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    HorizSync    30.0 - 60.0
    VertRefresh  50.0 - 60.0
    Option       "RightOf" "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:3:0:0"
    Screen      0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-1"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:3:0:0"
    Screen      1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
        SubSection "Display"
            Virtual   4000 1600
        EndSubSection
    DefaultDepth     24
EndSection
```

I think that the most important points are that there are two "Monitor" sections: One of which has the "RightOf" option, and just one "Screen" section. Many of the "solutions" I came across in my hunt had two screens, and this is what the command `sudo aticonfig --intial=dual-head` does by default.

Answer (score 0):

ARandR will allow you to do this. It is available through the software centre. It is a GUI for configuring external monitors. It will allow you to extend your laptop screen out to an external monitor and drag windows across. I have used it for my TV.

Go to the software centre and search for ARandR. Download and open it. It should automatically detect any ext monitor that is plugged in. LVDS1 will probably be the name of your laptop screen, while VGA1 or HDMI1 will probably be the name of the ext monitor. You can position the ext monitor to any side of your laptop screen by clicking and dragging the appropriate monitor. Having them overlapping completely will have the same display showing on both monitors, while having them side by side will extend your usable space over the two monitors. You can even have them slightly overlapping if you so wish. Play around a little. Once you have gotten a configuration you like click the 'tick' symbol. and it will be applied.

When using the system afterwards, should you wish to drag a window to the ext monitor, simply click on the titlebar and drag to the side of your laptop screen that you placed the ext monitor on and you will see your window begin to appear on the ext monitor.

Comment: While this is nice, a **good** answer would provide a more though step-by-step answer on what you needed to that to get it working.

Comment: *Changed* Thanks for the input. I'm new to the forum and still getting used to things :-)

Comment: You can install ARandR from the command-line with `sudo apt-get install arandr`, although you get the same functionality (with a better UI) using the 'Monitor Preferences' dialog that is installed by default.