# How to configure dual monitors with Ubuntu 14.04 and Radeon X1300/X1500

Tags: radeon, multiple-monitors

I recently upgraded my system from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. My dual monitors (which previously worked) now only mirror each other. I can't get them to stop mirroring, and one monitor has large black margins on the right and bottom edges.

```
lspci | grep AMD
```

gives Radeon X1300/X1550 as the graphics card.

When I click on "Displays", I see that the "Mirror displays" button is greyed out and is off. I have only one built in display detected, and clicking "Detect Displays" does not register the fact that I have two monitors.

I am using the default "radeon" Ubuntu driver. I have looked into the proprietary driver from AMD, but it was last updated in 2009 and (predictably) fails when I try to install it.

I know the X1300 is an old card - but is there any way I can configure it to run dual monitors on 14.04?

Comment: Does my answer here help you?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/537563/xorg-conf-for-two-monitors-single-ati-graphics-card/537567#537567

Comment: I tried your xorg.conf, and it hangs on the ubuntu load screen.  However the load screen seems to have the correct resolution.  I'm going to have to into recovery mode and check the logs to find out why it's not bringing me into the login screen, but I think you put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
kj@n36l:~$ xrandr -q

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
DVI-0 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
DVI-1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  

kj@n36l:~$ xrandr --output DVI-0 --primary --left-of DVI-1
```